# Interpreting array of coefficients for multiple regression

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I created a multiple regression model with sklearn and used .coef_ to get the coefficients. It returned an array of coefficients but I am not sure what each one represents. Could someone help me understand? Many thanks

Comment: Are you looking for information about the technicalities of `sklearn`'s regression model, especially in the case of multiple regression? Or information about the coefficients in OLS linear regression in general?

Comment: Haha I'm not exactly sure, I am quite new to this. I think I am the most confused about how each returned coefficient is different than the other. I've heard people talk about 'isolated' or 'constant' coefficients but I am not really sure what they are referring to. @AdamKern

Comment: Haha ok fair. There are a *lot* of resources out there that cover ordinary least squares (OLS) regressionn - it's basically the first method people learn in a stats class, and as a result, I'd really encourage you to just search "OLS explained" or "OLS coefficient interpretation". In (very, very) brief, each coefficient tells you how much a given "feature" of the data contributes to the outcome. "Big" (very positive or very negative) coefficients indicate that the feature is really important, "small" (closer to zero) coefficients indicate that the feature isn't that importannt

Comment: As for the `sklearn` specifics, you passed in a variable `X` that had the `n_samples` number of rows and `n_features` number of columns. The first value in the `.coef_` variable tells you the importance of that first column, the second value tells you the importance of the second column in `X`, etc